# billing and shipping address should have different address

Tags: shipping-address, billing-address

If i changed the "billing address" by clicking "change billing address" automatically

both "billing and shipping address" are changing....

I want " if we change billing address, only billing address should change and if we change

shipping address than only  "shipping address should change".

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance....[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set separate addresses by creating another address in the customer section and set that to `default shipping address`

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion. can you please tell me what code changes i have to do in which file ?

Comment: This is already default Magento functionality in the customer address section if you add an address

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. that's fine. we can do it in admin panel.

is there any option for customer to do that in "my account > address book" [not in checkout page"]

Comment: Hi, Have you got the solution for above question? If yes, Please share your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by passing

```
default_shipping =1 or default_billing= 1
```

value according to your requirement for this append

```
address_type = billing or address_type= shipping
```

in url.

Answer (score 1):

By the help of this code You can set separate addresses by creating another address.Which will set one as default billing and one as default shipping.

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Address">
        <plugin name="after_address_create" type="[Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\Model\CustomerAfterSave" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Plugin/Model/CustomerAfterSave.php**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerAfterSave
{

    /**
     * Construct function
     *
     * @param AddressFactory         $address
     * @param LoggerInterface        $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        AddressFactory $address,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->addressModel             = $address;
        $this->logger                   = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Create New address after magento address saved
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $subject
     * @param string $savedAddress
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $subject,
        $savedAddress
    ) {
        $customer = $savedAddress->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getDefaultBilling()  ==
            $customer->getDefaultShipping()) {
            $this->customerAddressSaveAfter($savedAddress);
        }
        return $savedAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Create new default shipping address
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $address
     * @return this
     */
    private function customerAddressSaveAfter($address)
    {
        try {
            if ($address->getIsDuplicate()) {
                return $this;
            }
            $oriAddress = $this->addressModel->create()->load($address->getId());
            $oriAddress->setIsDefaultShipping(true)
                    ->setIsDuplicate(true)
                    ->__clone();
            $oriAddress->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated version! Maybe late, but in Magento 2.3.5 they still haven't fixed it. So here my code. Little bit bulky but its works!

- etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost" type="Vendor\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost" />
</config>
```

- FormPost.php file

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Address;

/**
 * Class FormPost
 * @package Vendor\Module\Controller\Address
 */
class FormPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\FormPost
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    private $_customerFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
     */
    private $_addressFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        FormKeyValidator $formKeyValidator,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        HelperData $helperData,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $customerSession,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $formFactory,
            $addressRepository,
            $addressDataFactory,
            $regionDataFactory,
            $dataProcessor,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $resultForwardFactory,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $regionFactory,
            $helperData
        );
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Extract address from request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
     */
    protected function _extractAddress()
    {
        $existingAddressData = $this->getExistingAddressData();
        unset($existingAddressData['id']);

        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $addressForm */
        $addressForm = $this->_formFactory->create(
            'customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            $existingAddressData
        );
        $addressData = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest());
        $attributeValues = $addressForm->compactData($addressData);

        $this->updateRegionData($attributeValues);

        $billingParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing');
        $shippingParam =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping');
        $customerId = $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);

        if ($shippingParam) {
            $addressDataObject['attributeValues'] = $attributeValues;
            if ($customer->getDefaultShippingAddress() && $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getId() != $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getId()) {
                $addressDataObject['default_shipping'] =  $this->addressDataFactory->create()->setId($customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getId());
            } else {
                $addressDataObject['default_shipping'] = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
            }
            $shippingData =  array_merge($existingAddressData, $attributeValues);
            $addressDataObject['default_shipping']->getId();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $addressDataObject['default_shipping'],
                $shippingData,
                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class
            );
            $addressDataObject['default_shipping']->setCustomerId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId())
                ->setIsDefaultShipping(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam(
                        'default_shipping',
                        isset($existingAddressData['default_shipping']) ? $existingAddressData['default_shipping'] : false
                    )
                );
        }
        if ($billingParam) {
            $addressDataObject['attributeValues'] = $attributeValues;
            if ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress() && $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getId() != $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getId()) {
                $addressDataObject['default_billing'] = $this->addressDataFactory->create()->setId($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getId());
            } else {
                $addressDataObject['default_billing'] = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
            }
            $billingData =  array_merge($existingAddressData, $attributeValues);
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $addressDataObject['default_billing'],
                $billingData,
                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class
            );
            $addressDataObject['default_billing']->setCustomerId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId())
                ->setIsDefaultBilling(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam(
                        'default_billing',
                        isset($existingAddressData['default_billing']) ? $existingAddressData['default_billing'] : false
                    )
                );
        }
        if (!$shippingParam && !$billingParam) {
            $addressDataObject = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $addressDataObject,
                array_merge($existingAddressData, $attributeValues),
                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class
            );
            $addressDataObject->setCustomerId($this->_getSession()->getCustomerId())
                ->setIsDefaultBilling(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam(
                        'default_billing',
                        isset($existingAddressData['default_billing']) ? $existingAddressData['default_billing'] : false
                    )
                )
                ->setIsDefaultShipping(
                    $this->getRequest()->getParam(
                        'default_shipping',
                        isset($existingAddressData['default_shipping']) ? $existingAddressData['default_shipping'] : false
                    )
                );
        }
        return $addressDataObject;
    }

    /**
     * Process address form save
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $redirectUrl = null;
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->_getSession()->setAddressFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl(
                $this->_redirect->error($this->_buildUrl('*/*/edit'))
            );
        }

        try {
            $address = $this->_extractAddress();
            if (array_key_exists('attributeValues', $address)) {
                if (array_key_exists('default_shipping', $address['attributeValues'])) {
                    if (array_key_exists('default_billing', $address)) {
                        $this->_addressRepository->save($address['default_billing']);
                    }
                    if (array_key_exists('default_shipping', $address)) {
                        $this->_addressRepository->save($address['default_shipping']);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (array_key_exists('default_shipping', $address)) {
                        $this->_addressRepository->save($address['default_shipping']);
                    }
                    if (array_key_exists('default_billing', $address)) {
                        $this->_addressRepository->save($address['default_billing']);
                    }

                }
            } elseif (!array_key_exists('default_shipping', $address) && !array_key_exists('default_billing', $address)) {
                $this->_addressRepository->save($address);
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the address.'));
            $url = $this->_buildUrl('*/*/index', ['_secure' => true]);
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($url));
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $redirectUrl = $this->_buildUrl('*/*/index');
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('We can\'t save the address.'));
        }

        $url = $redirectUrl;
        if (!$redirectUrl) {
            $this->_getSession()->setAddressFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            $url = $this->_buildUrl('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }

        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
    }
}
```